# Problema comproando si existe un directorio con PHP

Tags: php, php5, filesystem

Estoy intentado comprobar si existe un directorio, y si no, crearlo, pero la pagína no me funciona cuando uso las funciones `file_exists` o `is_dir`.

Lo he intentado asi:

```
if(!file_exists( $path )
    mkdir($path);
```

Y así:

```
if(!is_dir ( $path )
    mkdir( $path );
```

Y también he intentado poner el `path` con diferentes formatos:

Según la documentación, si estoy en *Windows* debería hacerlo así:

```
$path= "C://Apache24/htdocs/uploads/carpeta"
```

Aunque también he intentado hacerlo así:

```
$path ="C:/Apache24/htdocs/uploads/carpeta"
```

Y así

```
$path= "./uploads/carpeta"
```

Incluso así:

```
$path= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/carpeta"
```

En todos los casos me falla. En local estoy trabajando en *Windows* pero supongo que cuando lo suba al servidor se tendrá que ejecutar en *Linux*.

¿Por qué fallan estas funciones? ¿Cómo se soluciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código **`!file_exists`** es correcto. Solo deberías tener en cuenta que falta un paréntesis.

Le agregué las llaves para que sea más claro aunque no son necesarias.

```
if(!file_exists( 'images/pics/' )) {
    echo "no existe";
}
```

Creo además que tienes una diferencia con `$path`. Es importante comprender cómo funciona eso, `$path` se referencia al lugar desde donde ejecutes la función `file_exists`.

Por ejemplo si estás en...

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\borrar\
```

... y quieres validar si existe el directorio

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\borrar\images\pics
```

... `$path` debería ser **`images/pics`** (notar barras cambiadas y la ruta relativa a donde se ejecuta la función).

Si por el contrario ejecutaras la función desde...

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\borrar\tmp
```

... entonces `$path` debería ser **`../images/pics`**, es decir bajar un directorio (../) y luego el camino a validar (`images/pics`).